# Firebird + Delphi - display joined fields value in dblabel

Tags: sql, database, delphi, firebird

I use Firebird db and I have a table that display some fields from other tables using Join. in the software UI made with Delphi I used dblookup to change the ID and set foreign table value.

I want to display other joined fields in dblabel component once the dblookup value changed by the user. Is there an automatic way to do that without using refresh?

please advise

SQL:

```
select 
   table1.f_id,
   table1.f2_id,
   table1.f_name,
   table2.alias_name, //<<<<<--- this is the field I want to display
from table1
   left outer join table2 on (table1.f2_id = table2.f2_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a good way is to read lookup fields in lookupbox and once a user select one I can read the other fields too

Answer (score 2):

You can use a lookup field for that. You need to create static fields for table1 first. Then add a new lookup field and wire it with appropriate values. Lookup fields are evaluated when the content of the joining fields change while a joined query has to be executed again to update the field value.